# Single word for one-sided friendship

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a single word to describe a one-sided friendship.

Comment: What makes the friendship one sided?

Comment: I think more details should be provided here. One-sided friendships could be had by mooches, stalkers, con men, or someone who is hugely insecure. I might use four different words, or the O.P. might be wanting a hypernym. Whichever it is, methinks some elaboration is in order.

Comment: Do you mean that one 'friend' does all the work to sustain the 'friendship'? i.e., is always the person to call, arrange meetings, always the one to visit, always the one to put themselves out for the other party...?

Answer (score 11):

If a friendship is one-sided, it could be described as *unrequited*.

Answer (score 9):

By *one-sided friendship* do you mean that a person wants to become a friend of another person's but is rejected as they do not hold mutual affection?
If yes, then that is not a friendship at all.

> Friendship is a relationship between two or more people who hold
>   *mutual affection* for each other.

You can say that the person has admiration (or respect) for the other but they are not friends.
Or the person trusts the other and is friendly to him/her but there is no mutual affection between them.

Comment: What about *one-sided love*? Does that exist? :P

Comment: @Mohit Well, theoretically *one-sided love* exists because love is an *emotion* of a strong affection and personal attachment, unlike an interpersonal relationship such as friendship.

Answer (score 8):

A one-sided affection is said to be *unreciprocated*.

Comment: As  to *undefenestrate* is really just to *fenestrate*, might not something that was *unreciprocated* simply be *procated*? :)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this fits in well, but I thought you could consider *unilateral*, too.

Answer (score 0):

A *forced* or *forceful* friendship.

Answer (score -2):

"Carry the torch" is an idiom to mean "have one sided love".